# ThreadPoolTaskScheduler change poolSize in runtime

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I create a scheduler:

```
@Bean
TaskScheduler taskScheduler(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("Test-");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

I wait next:

Each 1 second triggered my scheduled method and start 5 threads(`PoolSize(5)`) and each thread will make my logic. For that I create scheduled method in @Component bean:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyScheduler {

    private final TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    public MyScheduler(TaskScheduler taskScheduler) {
        this.taskScheduler = taskScheduler;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L)
    public void test(){
        taskScheduler.schedule(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(9000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log.info("test");
        }, new Date());

    }
}
```

It works fine.

each 1 second start `test()` method and work 9 seconds. On 5 secon I have full threadPool and wait first free thread. If I set `sleep(5000L)` - threadPool can not fill up.

But now I need to change the poolSize in runtime. For example from 5 to 10. How can I do it?

Comment: You aren't scheduling threads, you are scheduling tasks which are processed by 5 threads. Why would you need to expand the poolsize?

Comment: @ M. Deinum I poll the third-party system with a very short time interval. I do this in N threads. Periodically, you need to take data at a faster rate and for this the number of threads that poll it changes. believe me, I was shocked to learn that the system works this way, but it exists and it really works.

Comment: My system sends a request to another system. the third-party system says - well, I accepted your request and put it in the queue for processing. And after that I start constantly asking her - are there any answers for me?

Comment: But why would you need more threads for that? Design the tasks in such a way that they poll, if there is nothing, let them sleep for a bit (not 10 seconds) and poll again. You don't need 10 or 100 threads for that.

Comment: @M. Deinum I did not understand very well what you mean. My server will be installed in different locations. by default there will be 50 threads and intrudal in 10 milliseconds. This will be enough to parse the third-party server queue. Most answers will be - for you there is nothing. But there are times when the queue is full, and my server will not be able to disassemble it. you need to increase the number of threads. This is my technical task from the lead

Comment: Imho that task is wrong... If you need more threads then create more threads. But that isn't a solution but rather a hack/workaround for the real problem. The real problem, imho, is that it is implemented in a wrong way. With a proper implementation you can achieve what you want with the same amount of threads.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can resize the scheduler at runtime by calling setPoolSize() (see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html#setPoolSize-int-)

The problem is: you need to have a reference to the specific class `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` instead of the interface `TaskScheduler`.

You need to decide if you want to change the references from `TaskScheduler` to `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` without breaking anyhting in your code